# Unsatisfied Link Error When Loading JNI Library

Tags: java, c, macos, java-native-interface

I am writing a simple Hello World Java program to call code from a native library. However, when I run the program, I receive the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no TestJNI in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1764)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1044)
    at TestJNI.<clinit>(TestJNI.java:4)
```

Below is the code:
Java:

```
//filename: TestJNI.java

public class TestJNI{

    static{
        System.loadLibrary("TestJNI");
    }   

    private native void helloWorld();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TestJNI().helloWorld();
   }
}
```

C:

```
//filname:TestJNI.c

#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "TestJNI.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_TestJNI_helloWorld(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj){
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return;
}
```

The C file is compiled with the following compiler, flags and arguments:
`clang -o TestJNI.jnilib -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers -lc -shared TestJNI.c`

Then the Java application is run as below:
`java -Djava.library.path=. TestJNI`

I am compiling and running the files on Mac OS X Yosemite. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that `java.library.path` variable points to the directory which contains the TestJNI library.
You can try

`System.setProperty("java.library.path", "...directory path...");`

Alternatively, use `System.load("...full path to TestJNI...");` which takes the full path to the library (including the file extension). (`System.loadLibrary` infers the file extension I believe)

Comment: I am compiling the C file to the same directory that the Java application is in. Do I still need to include the full path name?

Comment: You only need to include the full path if you use `System.load` to load the library. If you use `System.loadLibrary`, you include only the name of the library file ( no extension). In the latter case you must also ensure java.library.path is pointing to the directory. I suggest the former case, it is more explicit.

Comment: Your solution works! However, I would still like to know how to load the library without having the specify the full path name. Is there something wrong with passing `-Djava.library.path=.` as an argument when I run the application? Alternatively, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I have been getting unpredictable results with java.library.path, especially across multiple platforms. Please accept the answer if it is the solution!

Comment: It should be possible to pass location as ".". However, make sure your locations are ok. In addition to that, remember that shared libraries have slightly different naming convention in OS X (comparing to Linux). Take a look here, for very basic sample: http://jnicookbook.pl/hello-world/

Answer (score 0):

Your library should be named something .so so that it can be loaded as a shared library.  I believe that your compilation line should look something like:

clang -shared -undefined dynamic_lookup -o TestJNI.so -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers -lc TestJNI.c

Comment: I am on OS X so the library file extension is correct as a .jnilib file. Do you have any other suggestions?